# Eclipse UML2 Tools - Sequence diagram

Tags: eclipse, tool-uml

I have spent at least 2 weeks now trying to find out how to do
something really simple on UML2Tools but i just cant figure it out. I
even posted at the Eclipse newsgroups but for some reason not even one
response so hopefully somebody here can help.

I am using UML2Tools in eclipse and trying to create a sequence
diagram. My problem is i cant figure out how to label the transitions
between objects in sequence diagram. For some reason every transition/
message between objects are automatically labeled as "1:*". Please
does anyone know how i can correctly label a transition in a sequence
diagram? (i.e. give it names like modifyProduct(), validate() etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to open the property view and change the name manually in the name field box, it could work but I don't have time to check it because it would require to download the plugin, to install it, to create a sequence diagram etc.....
If it doesn't work then it seems that this option has not been coded. Don't forget that over 50% of the job needed to be a professional tool has never been done because this open project is provided by the former borland team which is still interested to sell Togethersoft tools !! So why to create a better open source  than the professional tool?

You can try to use UMLlet for a quick design, no model just a kind of powerpoint. If you have a budget then try RSA *(very nice sequence diagram)* or Omondo *(sequence diagram not as good as RSA but the class diagram is a lot better and really perfect java integration).*